# Can cmd echo take input from a file that is redirected to stdin?

Tags: echo, stdin

As we all know, if we type `echo abc` it will print `abc` to the terminal.

But what if we put `abc` to a file try and type `echo < try`?

I tried but it just printed an empty line.

> $ echo < try
>
> $

Comment: Are you looking for `cat <filename>` instead? This post might be useful to understand why `echo` is not used for files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/redirecting-the-content-of-a-file-to-the-command-echo

Comment: `echo` does not read from `stdin`, so redirecting its `stdin` does not achieve anything. You can tell the shell to place the content of the file into the command line by doing `echo \`cat try\`` (those are backtick characters) or `echo $(cat try)`, depending on which shell you are using.